# About partially polarized light and the degree of polariztion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, polarization

When I was taking Optics course, I found there were several questions about polarization of light. I use the textbook of Hecht.

1. It seems that the definition of degree of polarization may be not so well-defined if $V=\frac{I_{max}-I_{min}}{I_{max}+I_{min}}$. For a elliptical polarized light, there is no natural polarized part, but still $V\neq 0$.
2. I found it hard to deal with partially polarized light. First the definition. What is the definition of partially polarized light? Light with $0<V<1$?
3. Is all partially polarized light can be presented by the superposition of a plane polarized light and a natural light? I suppose it is true but why? Is there any formal explanation?
4. Consider a real problem. Suppose there is a beam of light incident on an air-glass interface with $n_{ti}=1.5$ at a certain degree, say $30°$. Then how to characterize the reflected light or the transmitted light since they are all partially polarized. What is $V$ for these lights? I gauss the answer may be $V=\frac{|r_p|^2-|r_s|^2}{|r_p|^2+|r_s|^2}$. But I can't convince my self why this correspondes to the definition above. (This is essentially a problem in Hecht.)

Thanks a lot! I am really confused with that.

Comment: #2: think of it as combination of polarized light and unpolarized, or randomly polarized light.  The ratio of those two defines the "partial"-ness.  #3: I think you can have either plane or circularly polarized light superposed w/ unpolarized.

Comment: #2: But if it is the definition of partially polarized light in 2, how to explain an elliptical polarized light is a partially polarized light?  #3: I guess so, since there is no prefer in plane or circularly polarization. But still, is there any strict treatment in this decomposition? Thx a lot!

Comment: #3 - No. For example, if you mix 1 watt of circularly polarized light with 1 watt of unpolarized light.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems that the definition of degree of polarization may be not so well-defined if $V=\frac{I_{max}-I_{min}}{I_{max}+I_{min}}$. For a
>   elliptical polarized light, there is no natural polarized part, but
>   still $V\neq 0$.

This definition is used in *measurements.*  Elliptical polarized light can be fully polarized, i.e. $V=1$ (theoretically).  I really don't like that Hecht uses V here, as that is also used for *visibility* which is an interference thing (but I understand why, see below).

Specifically, we define the Stokes parameters 
$$\mathbf{s} = \begin{pmatrix}s_0 \\ s_1 \\ s_2 \\ s_3\end{pmatrix}$$.

Then the degree of polarization $$\mathscr{P} = \frac{\sqrt{s_1^2 + s_2^2 + s_3^2}}{s_0}$$

Partial polarization is a statistical quantity, it is the result of taking the *ensemble* average over some domain of the irradiance projection through polarization elements.  This means that it is really a *coherence* (i.e. interference) phenomena.

> I found it hard to deal with partially polarized light. First the definition. What is the definition of partially polarized light? Light
>   with $0<V<1$?

This is because for a deterministic ideal, mathematical point in space-time, partial polarization doesn't exist.  Partial polarization is the statistical time average of a time or space or space-time region.  Yes, this definition implies that $0<V<1$.

This is because optical detectors only measure irradiance, not optical field.  In longer wavelength regions, antennas can capture both phase and amplitude and the polarization can be reconstructed from those parameters, but this is not the case for optical detectors.

Mathematically :

$s_0 = \langle E_x^2 + E_y^2\rangle\\
s_1 = \langle E_x^2 - E_y^2\rangle\\
s_2 = 2\langle E_xE_y\cos(\delta)\rangle\\
s_3 = 2\langle E_xE_y\sin(\delta)\rangle
$

where $E_x$ and $E_y$ are the classical *electric field* components in the $x$ and $y$ directions (in optics we use the $z$-axis as the direction of energy flux), both functions of $t$ of course, and

$$\langle f(t) \rangle = lim_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(t) dt $$

is the time average, and $\delta$ is the *phase difference between $E_x$ and $E_y$.*

Open access source aren't great for this explanation, but [this paper](http://www.ras.ucalgary.ca/~jocat/polarisation_2008.pdf) may help.

> Is all partially polarized light can be presented by the superposition
>   of a plane polarized light and a natural light? I suppose it is true
>   but why? Is there any formal explanation?

Not a super-position of natural light and polarized light, but a super-position of *purely polarized* light and of *completely depolarized* light.  It is obvious why if we look at the definition of $\mathscr{P}$, if $\mathscr{P} = 0$, then the light is completely depolarized and $s_1 = s_2 = s_3 = 0$.

Then

$$\mathbf{s} = (1-\mathscr{P})\begin{pmatrix}s_0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} + \mathscr{P}\begin{pmatrix}s_0 \\ s_1 \\ s_2 \\ s_3\end{pmatrix}$$

Assuming that the Stokes parameters are linear, (which follows from the linearity of optical fields in most dielectrics, air, etc.) then I'll leave it to you to verify this is correct.

> Consider a real problem. Suppose there is a beam of light incident on
>   an air-glass interface with $n_{ti}=1.5$ at a certain degree, say
>   $30°$. Then how to characterize the reflected light or the transmitted
>   light since they are all partially polarized. What is $V$ for these
>   lights? I guess the answer may be
>   $V=\frac{|r_p|^2-|r_s|^2}{|r_p|^2+|r_s|^2}$. But I can't convince my
>   self why this corresponds to the definition above. (This is
>   essentially a problem in Hecht.)

What you have written for $V$ here is called the *diattenuation, not the depolarization.*  This is the difference in amplitude between the the $s$ and $p$ polarizations reflected.  Remember that $s$ and $p$ are *defined by the geometry and symmetries of the problem.*

Answer (score 1):

Here is some possibly useful information from Goodman's "Statistical Optics."  (Sorry about the lack of symbol quality --  so much for cut/paste from a PDF)

> Light from a thermal source is regarded as unpolarized if two conditions are
>       met. First, we require that the intensity of the light passed by a polarization
>       analyzer, situated in a plane perpendicular to the direction of propagatof the wave, be independent of the rotational orientation of the analyzer.
>       Second, we require that any two orthogonal field components $u_x( P, t) $ and
>       $u_y(P, t)$ have the property that $(u_x(t + T)u_t(t))$ is identically zero for all
>       rotational orientations of the $X- Y$ coordinate axes and for all delays $T$.

Later, in section 4.3.3,

> We define the degree of polarization of the wave as the ratio of
>       the intensity of the polarized component to the total intensity,

I'd recommend reading section 4.3 in its entirety.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got a quick view of section 4.3 of this book. Now my question about #1 and #2 is clear. The way Goodman defines degree of polarization using coherence matrix is very similar to density matrix in quantum statistics. But for #3 and #4, I still get confused. I begin to think that #3 is not true generally.